# External 1TB WD USB 3.0 HDD is not detecting. Working perfectly fine in Windows

Tags: external-hdd, automount

My 1TB USB 3.0 was working fine earlier in Ubuntu as well as Windows. But lately it is not at all being detected in Ubuntu. It still works fine in Windows. I did update my Ubuntu to 12.10 but I am not sure if that caused the issue.

When I connect my HDD and run dmesg | tail:

```
[   47.804676] usb 4-3: >Device not responding to set address. 
[   48.008575] usb 4-3: >Device not responding to set address. 
[   48.212421] usb 4-3: >device not accepting address 9, error -71 
[   48.324451] usb 4-3: >Device not responding to set address. 
[   48.528340] usb 4-3: >Device not responding to set address. 
[   48.732165] usb 4-3: >device not accepting address 10, error -71 
[   48.844138] usb 4-3: >Device not responding to set address. 
[   49.048179] usb 4-3: >Device not responding to set address. 
[   49.251881] usb 4-3: >device not accepting address 11, error -71 
[   49.251907] hub 4-0:1.0: >unable to enumerate USB device on port 3
```

The output of sudo fdisk -l is :

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00030cde

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048  1332981759   666489856   83  Linux
/dev/sda2      1332981760  1953523711   310270976    5  Extended
/dev/sda5      1332983808  1349365759     8190976   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6      1349367808  1953523711   302077952    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a2519

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048   103368703    51683328    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       103368704   154568703    25600000   83  Linux
/dev/sdb3       154568704   234440703    39936000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

/dev/sda and /dev/sdb are my 2 internal HDDs. But the external one which should be /dev/sdc is not even being shown though it is connected and the LED on the HDD is glowing.

Someone had suggested adding `blacklist uas` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. Tried that as well. But still not working. Can someone help me out.

Comment: I found some info here : [link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/usb3-western-digital-external-hdd-no-longer-detected-after-upgrade-to-3-5-4-kernel-4175431882/). It seems to be caused by kernel. I will go home and check it properly.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will resolve your issue, but it's worth a try :

Connect your Device

Pull the usb cable just a little bit out from the computer side.. ( just a tiny bit) and wait for a couple of minutes..

if it starts working then you may push the usb - cable back in properly.

I faced similar issue..

If it doesn't work then sorry.. :(

Comment: No I tried that. It doesn't do any thing. No msg or pop up or anything :-(

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar case and I am using an Asus laptop N53SV.  My portable drive is a 1TB Transcend StoreJet 25H3P USB 3.0.  It can't be detected in the USB 3.0 port located on the left side but it is being detected on the left side ports (USB 2.0). I read somewhere in the net to turn the laptop off and then plug the 1TB USB 3.0 on the USB 3.0 port and then turn the laptop back on.  This is not the grandest solution that I've got but it works.  I am on 3.2.0-32-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 26 21:33:09 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux